# Search view voice search doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to search view. i implement one in my `toolbar` via `onCreateOptionsMenu`
 and define it in item tag in `menu_main`

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_serarch"
        android:title="serarch"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"

       />
```

it works just fine but **voice recognition icon** and its functionality **doesn't show** even I handle the necessary methods.

Answer (score 0):

[You can check out the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Update: If your SearchActivity is the same one, you can override onNewIntent and handle the Search intent there. Also make your activity as singleTop, that way only one instance of the activity will stay on top.

Hope this helps and please do notify if you find a solution.

Cheers!